# How to downgrade in Laravel Framework? (5.6 to 5.5)

Tags: laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6, downgrade

I have a project which is done with Laravel 5.6. But My current server doesn't have php 7.1 installed yet. How is it possible to downgrade to Laravel 5.5?

Comment: You can remove your composer.lock and vendor files/folders and change laravel version to 5.5.* in composer.json file. 

I am not sure, If this method will work or not so Just take backup before you try this method. Let me know if it works or what issue you having. All the best!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I also down graded my project also, but then I was getting ton of errors. But most of them were about unfamiliar key words and unsupported packages. So, success depends on your project’s dependencies and also your effort.

Follow these steps.

1. Backup your project
2. Change the value of Laravel version inside the composer.json to Laravel 5.5
3. Delete vendor folder
4. Run composer install

> ** By then you will have to take care of any issues in your own code because there should be new functionalities in earlier versions which
>   is not used in older.

Or

Go to [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade) page and do the instructions in reverse order

Comment: Yup. Those four steps work. Only thing to look at is the dependancies, and of course the php you are using. Other than that it's pretty simple.

Comment: It's necessary to delete  composer.lock  file, then run  composer install

Comment: You need to go to the official github releases and choose the version of your choice like 5.5 and copy the packages settings from there to your composer.json. Also you have to go to the packages that you have already and find their older versions if any exist for 5.5 and update that into your composer.json file and then follow the above mentioned steps.

Comment: i installed a new 5.5 project installed composer dependencies copied controllers,models,views and route file is this a correct way to do so ?